# How to compare data from multiple csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv, data-science

I have 25 csv files with four columns each one and I have to compare 1 column named `City` in all 25 CSVs, then write the output in csv as which city is present in how many files with file name.
e.g.

In excel I want New york in first 0 column first row and then in next column onward I want to get the file names where the city newyork is present. Like `csv_output.csv`:

```
New york File 1, File 2, File 3, File 5, File 25
Jakarta  File 1, File 7, File 19.
```

How to do it using Python, Pandas or CSV or any other option.

Currently I checked initially for two csv but that is not working too.
My requirement is for 25 CSV files.

```
import pandas as pd
Data1 = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/File1.csv')
Data2  = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/File2.csv', usecols=['City'])
for df in [Data1, Data2]:
    df['City'] = df['City'].str.rstrip()
result = pd.merge(netscan, computer, on='City', how='outer')

result.to_csv('Report.csv', index=False)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach.  First, collect all 25 CSV files into one data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
dfs = list()
for file in files:
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    df['file'] = file
    dfs.append(df)
dfs = pd.concat(dfs)
```

Next, compute summary stats:

```
result = dfs.groupby('file')['city'].count()
```

Here is info on posting examples:  [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: import pandas as pd
import glob

path = r'C:/Users/' # use your path

all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")

dfs = list()
for file in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    df['file'] = file
    dfs.append(df)
dfs = pd.concat(dfs)
#print (dfs)

result = dfs.groupby('City')['City'].count()
print (result)

I  made above changes and I got result with 
Name: City, Length: 947002, dtype: int64
With that city coloum and in front of it I am getting count like
Newyork : 1
Jakarta : 1
But my requirement is to get
Newyork : File 1, File 2
Jakarta : File 19,  In new CSV.